# Keras model in double for loop

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am using the same keras model in double for loops but want make sure the iterations are totally independent as follows.

```
Dense network
```

LSTM network

````
X = concatenate([Dense,LSTM])

Y = Dense(1)(X)
model = Model(inputs=[Dense_input,LSTMN_input], outputs=Y)
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='RMSProp', metrics=['accuracy'])
es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_acc', min_delta=0, patience=10, restore_best_weights=True)

for q in range(A):
    ```
    add new samples to training data
    ```
    for w in range(B):
        ```
        model.fit([dense, lstm],output)
        ```
    ```
    make some predictions and get new samples
````

What is the efficient way to implement this?

Comment: So, you want to actually *reset* the model for each iteration of the inner `for` loop?

Comment: Seconding desernaut, I'd like to ask you a bit of elaboration of "totally independent".

Comment: Yes, reset the model so that current iteration model does not get mixed up with the previous one, i.e. weights, biases etc. In other words each iteration I want an empty model ready for fitting. Will creating a class for this model help?